# Using regex and math

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get some math out of a string, with no decimals it all worked perfectly, but when I started adding them in it stopped working, it doesn't seem to leave the dot in there. I think my regex is right but can someone correct me?

```
result = re.findall('\d+\.?\d*\*\d+\.?\d*', e)
for x in result:
    lst = x.split("*")
    print lst
    e = e.replace(x, str(float(lst[0])*float(lst[1])))
```

so if I put in `"1.0*1.0"` it should come out with 1.0 but it comes out with 100.0, this is because of the regex.

print lst comes out with ["10", "10"] and not ["1.0", "1.0"] so we can say that its not the line after that. Any ideas?

My understanding is that `+` means one or more `?` means 0 or 1 and `*` means 0 or more

Comment: It works for me... (all said and done, `e` equals `"1.0"`)

Comment: Works for me too . . . I'm guessing [GIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out); when you say put in `"1.0*1.0"`, is that what e is set to before?

Comment: This isn't your problem here, but you're much better off getting in the habit of using raw strings for regexes (`r'\d+\.?.....'`), so you don't get confused if you try to add a `\b` or something.

Comment: I tried this by its self and it worked, I think I should try out the rest

Comment: Ive just realised whats happened, I used a checker to make sure that it only had `\ * + - ^` I need to add `.` in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input string was only coming in as 10*10 so I obviously did something wrong, in another module I had this code here that was done before I added decimals in...

```
acceptedChars = set(string.digits + "[]()+-/*^=!<>" + string.letters)
newL = ''.join([ x for x in e if x in acceptedChars])
e = newL
```

this meant that `.` would be deleted, so I needed to add this back in. So now I'm using this code:

```
acceptedChars = set(string.digits + "[]()+-/*^=!<>." + string.letters)
newL = ''.join([ x for x in e if x in acceptedChars])
e = newL
```

If anyone else could think of any mathematical symbols that should be in there it would help in the future. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the `[ .. ]` in `''.join([ .. ])`: `''.join(x for x in e if x in acceptedChars)` works exactly the same and is probably more efficient too. :)